# What software is generally used to create these animated illustrations?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, illustration

I am a fan of these type of illustrated gifs:
[image]
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/288987/screenshots/2984258/wf-43.gif
And many more.

I have come a long way to improve my illustrating skills and I would love to start animating these kind of things, but I have no idea what *software* I should start learning. I have found very few tutorials on these kind of things, leaving me to believe I might be using the *wrong keywords* to search.

- Is there a name for these kind of flat-ish animations?
- What software is generally used to create this?
- What keywords should I use to search for tutorials on this?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable thread of questions. But its obviously a broad subject. Because your essentially asking how is animation done. On a very general level.

Comment: @joojaa Well I'm not asking you to explain, but more to guide me to the tools/information I need to learn this? Maybe I need to rephrase the title... Still might be quite broad but the software you linked is actually very helpful.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haa7n3UGyDc for starters

Comment: @joojaa I should have maybe noted that I do know the very basics of animation such as squash and stretch, as I had to learn them in school. It stops there though :)

Answer (score 2):

Cell shaded animation has been around for far longer than the flat movement, so its called traditional animation. The animation world is more fragmented than graphics design world so you have many options depending on your workflow i suggest you use:

- https://www.toonboom.com/products/harmony

Other software are:

- Flash -> Adobe Animate
- After effects

But what you should google to do this is a bit premature. Theres quite a bit of basics to know before you should start on this project. Be ready to spend a month on this.

Comment: This is just something I would like to learn, there's no project or deadline tied to it. So I don't mind the timeframe at all. Thanks for the info!